# how to reference the base folder in a asp.net website project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My urls when I run the asp.net website project (in vs.net 2008) looks like:

```
http://localhost:54269/www/Default.aspx
```

So referencing things like:

```
/sytle/css.css
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Why does my project have a '/www' folder?  Did I set things up wrong?

Comment: Look in the Web tab of your project's properties and see if "www" appears somewhere. That's assuming this is a Web Application project (`File->New Project`), and not a web site (`File->New Web Site`).

Answer (score 3):

This might be the virtual directory. Depending on where you are hosting your application (IIS or running in Visual Studio's built in web server) this is setup differently. In order to avoid problems referencing static files you could use:

```
<%= Page.ResolveClientURL("~/sytle/css.css") %>
```

Comment: but what about referencing controls like ~/controls/header.ascx

Comment: The ~ (tilda) means it's a "rooted path". More info: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/132081.aspx  http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101145&seqNum=2

Comment: Its better to use ResolveUrl in the example you presented. when using ResolveClientUrl, the ~/ is relative to the current page, not the site root. See this page for more info: http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/ResolveUrl-vs-ResolveClientUrl.aspx